# publishing PWA on app stores : google play and ios itunes

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to publish an app on publishing PWA on app stores
 google play and ios itunes. Without creating a buggy with cordova which creates a tons of issues to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is way to publish your PWAs to Android AppStore.
**TWAs**
Trusted Web Activities are a new way to integrate your web-app content such as your PWA with your Android app using a protocol based on Custom Tabs.

**TWAs** uses the **Digital Asset Links protocol** and API enable an app or website to make public, verifiable statements about other apps or websites. For example, a website can declare that it is associated with a specific Android app, or it can declare that it wants to share user credentials with another website.

Checkout the following [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa#remove_the_url_bar) for complete guide to launch PWA to Appstore by Google Developers forum and tutorial guide on medium by Maximiliano Firtman [here](https://medium.com/@firt/google-play-store-now-open-for-progressive-web-apps-ec6f3c6ff3cc)

Comment: what abt iOs,, isthere similar link / tutorial

Comment: There is no similar thing to TWAs on Apple AppStore and I don’t know about Apple is pushing something like this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try the documentation [Package Your Cordova App for Publishing to an App Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/publishing/publish-to-a-store?view=toolsforcordova-2017).

> Before you can build your application for deployment to any device
>   through a public app store, you must first configure Visual Studio
>   with the information it needs to complete the process of packaging and
>   signing the application for deployment through an app store.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started investigating this myself, have you tried PWA builder? https://www.pwabuilder.com?

It can generate packages for Windows, Android and iOS.